# Antlr4 can't recognize a single number and bracket. I don't know what the problem is?

Tags: antlr4, sql-parser

```
lexer grammar TransformLexer;

@header { package com.abc.g4.gen; }

channels { DPCOMMENT, ERRORCHANNEL }


@members {
  /**
   * Verify whether current token is a valid decimal token (which contains dot).
   * Returns true if the character that follows the token is not a digit or letter or underscore.
   *
   * For example:
   * For char stream "2.3", "2." is not a valid decimal token, because it is followed by digit '3'.
   * For char stream "2.3_", "2.3" is not a valid decimal token, because it is followed by '_'.
   * For char stream "2.3W", "2.3" is not a valid decimal token, because it is followed by 'W'.
   * For char stream "12.0D 34.E2+0.12 "  12.0D is a valid decimal token because it is folllowed
   * by a space. 34.E2 is a valid decimal token because it is followed by symbol '+'
   * which is not a digit or letter or underscore.
   */
  public boolean isValidDecimal() {
    int nextChar = _input.LA(1);
    if (nextChar >= 'A' && nextChar <= 'Z' || nextChar >= '0' && nextChar <= '9' ||
      nextChar == '_') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

// SKIP

SPACE:                               [ \t\r\n]+     -> channel(HIDDEN);
SPEC_MYSQL_COMMENT:                  '/*!' .+? '*/' -> channel(DPCOMMENT);
COMMENT_INPUT:                       '/*' .*? '*/'  -> channel(HIDDEN);
LINE_COMMENT:                        (
                                       ('--' [ \t] | '#') ~[\r\n]* ('\r'? '\n' | EOF)
                                       | '--' ('\r'? '\n' | EOF)
                                     ) -> channel(HIDDEN);


STRING
    : DQUOTA_STRING
    ;

EQ  : '==';
NEQ : '<>';
NEQJ: '!=';
LT  : '<';
LTE : '<=';
GT  : '>';
GTE : '>=';

PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
ASTERISK: '*';
SLASH: '/' ;
PERCENT: '%';
RSHIFT: '>>';
LSHIFT: '<<';

IS:    'IS'    | 'is';
NULL:  'NULL'  | 'null';
TRUE:  'TRUE'  | 'true';
FALSE: 'FALSE' | 'false';
LIKE:  'LIKE'  | 'like';

OR:  'OR'  | 'or' | '|';
AND: 'AND' | '&&' | 'and' | '&';
IN:  'IN'  | 'in';
NOT: 'NOT' | '!'  | 'not';

CASE: 'CASE' | 'case';
WHEN: 'WHEN' | 'when';
THEN: 'THEN' | 'then';
ELSE: 'ELSE' | 'else';
END:  'END'  | 'end';

JOIN: '||';

ID:                                  [@]ID_LITERAL+;
// DOUBLE_QUOTE_ID:                  '"' ~'"'+ '"';
REVERSE_QUOTE_ID:                    '`' ~'`'+ '`';
NAME:                                ID_LITERAL+;

fragment ID_LITERAL:                 [a-zA-Z_0-9\u0080-\uFFFF]*?[a-zA-Z_$\u0080-\uFFFF]+?[a-zA-Z_$0-9\u0080-\uFFFF]*;
fragment DQUOTA_STRING:              '"' ( '\\'. | '""' | ~('"'| '\\') )* '"' | '\'' ( ~('\''|'\\') | ('\\' .) )* '\'';
fragment DEC_DIGIT:                  '0' .. '9'+;

// Last tokens must generate Errors

ERROR_RECONGNIGION:                  .    -> channel(ERRORCHANNEL);

NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;


BYTELENGTH_LITERAL
    : DEC_DIGIT+ ('B' | 'K' | 'M' | 'G')
    ;

INTEGER_VALUE
    : [-]*DEC_DIGIT+
    ;

DECIMAL_VALUE
    : DEC_DIGIT+ EXPONENT
    | DECIMAL_DIGITS EXPONENT? {isValidDecimal()}?
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    : (LETTER | DEC_DIGIT | '_')+
    ;

BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER
    : '`' ( ~'`' | '``' )* '`'
    ;

COMMA: ',' ;

LEFT_BRACKET
    : '(('
    ;

RGIHT_BRACKET
    : '))'
    ;

LEFT_BRACKET1
    : '{{'
    ;

RGIHT_BRACKET1
    : '}}'
    ;

START
    : '$'
    ;

fragment DECIMAL_DIGITS
    : DEC_DIGIT+ '.' DEC_DIGIT+
    | '.' DEC_DIGIT+
    ;

fragment EXPONENT
    : 'E' [+-]? DEC_DIGIT+
    ;

fragment LETTER
    : [A-Z]
    ;

SIMPLE_COMMENT
    : '--' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n'? -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

BRACKETED_COMMENT
    : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

WS
    : [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

```
parser grammar TransformParser;

options { tokenVocab=TransformLexer; }
@header { package com.abc.g4.gen; }

finalExpression:
    (booleanExpression | caseExpression | resultExpression | function) EOF
    ;

caseExpression
    : CASE whenClause+ (ELSE (elseExpression=resultExpression | caseExpression))? END       #whenExpression
    | constant                                                                              #constantDefault
    ;

values:
 constant               #constantValue
 | ID                   #idValue
 ;

valueCalc:
     LEFT_BRACKET valueCalc RGIHT_BRACKET
    | valueCalc ('*'|'/'|'%')    valueCalc
    | valueCalc ('+'|'-')        valueCalc
    | valueCalc ('<<'|'>>')      valueCalc
    | values
    ;

booleanExpression
    : left=booleanExpression operator=AND                   right=booleanExpression         #logicalBinary1
    | left=booleanExpression operator=OR                    right=booleanExpression         #logicalBinary
    | NOT booleanExpression                                                                 #logicalNot
    | predicated                                                                            #predicatedExpression
    | left=valueCalc         operator=comparisonOperator    right=valueCalc                 #comparison4
    | booleanValue                                                                          #booleanValueTag
    ;

predicated
    : (values | valueCalc) IN  values (values)*
    ;

whenClause:
    WHEN condition=booleanExpression THEN (result=resultExpression | caseExpression);

resultExpression:
    predicated | values | valueCalc;

constant
    : NULL              #nullLiteral
    | STRING            #typeConstructor
    | number            #numericLiteral
    | booleanValue      #booleanLiteral
    | STRING+           #stringLiteral
    ;

comparisonOperator
    : EQ | NEQ | NEQJ | LT | LTE | GT | GTE | IS
    ;

booleanValue
    : TRUE | FALSE
    ;

number
    : MINUS? DECIMAL_VALUE            #decimalLiteral
    | MINUS? INTEGER_VALUE            #integerLiteral
    ;

qualifiedName
    : NAME
    ;

function
    : qualifiedName (params) #functionCall
    ;

param:
    valueCalc | values | function | booleanExpression
    ;

params:
   param (param)*
   ;
```

I can recognize numbers of multiple characters, but I cannot recognize numbers of single characters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxKU3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqOYy.png)

And parentheses cannot change the priority of expression calculation. What's wrong with my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUyWp.png)

I try to replace '(', ')' with '((', '))' or '{{', '}}'. It can be done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnY4n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: delete 'ERROR_ RECONGNATION 'Then it's OK